# How to send multiple request at same time

Tags: jmeter

I am testing a website for load test having following pages

- Home Page
- Login Page
- Blog Page
- Selected Blog Page
- Post on Selected Blog

I want to send request for each page at same time with different number of users. At now i am doing this in following  way
Thread 1 (user 500)

1. Home Page

Thread 2 (300 user)

1. Blog Page

Thread 3 (100 user)

1. Selected Blog Page

But when i use login functionality, then how can i achieve this task because login requests sets some cookies data and other information about user and Post page also need some data from Selected Blog Page.
I want to achieve following:
Lets suppose 500 user logged-in then 300 user should hit Blog Page, 100 user hit Selected Blog Page and 100 User hit the Post on the Blog Page , but all things should be at same time.

Answer (score 7):

I see 2 ways with some assumptions,

Assumption : by saying Thread you mean Threadgroup and you have 3 threadgroups each with only 1 request i.e.

```
Threadgroup1 
  home Page 
Threadgroup2
  blog page
Threadgroup3 
  select blog
```

Options :

1. For each threadgroup you can make simultaneous load by making rampup time 0,delay 0. By doing this Jmeter will start all threads(users) at a time.
2. use Synchronization timer (standard way) : this will block no. of threads till a count is achieved and then releases all threads at once to generate heavy load at a given point of time.

Scenario 1 would be, 
each threadgroup with reqd no of users and rampup 0
[image]

Scenario 2 would be,
single threadgroup with max no of users but before each req. synchronization timer which will wait for specific no. of users (100 for example). read help about synchronization timer.
[image]

Comment: Yes Thread mean ThreadGroup. Using multiple thread is right approach or not??

Comment: Also how do this for login scenario....which i describe in my question. Can you help me with structure.

Comment: Using multiple threadgroups with single isnt invalid.It totally depends on your testing.